# Convert DStream of case class with joda.DateTime to Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, jodatime, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to save a DStream into HDFS using parquet format. The problem is that my case class use joda.DateTime while Spark SQL doesn't support this. For example:

```
    case class Log (timestamp: DateTime, ...dozen of other fields here...)
```

But I got error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.joda.time.DateTime is not supported when trying to convert RDD to DF:

```
    def output(logdstream: DStream[Log]) {
        logdstream.foreachRDD(elem => {
           val df = elem.toDF()
           df.saveAsParquet(...)
        });
    }
```

My models are complex and have a lot of fields, so I don't want to write different case classes to get rid of the joda.DateTime. Another option would be save directly from json to parquet but it's not ideal. Is there an easy way to do automatic conversion from joda.DateTime to sql.Timestamp to be used with spark (convert to Spark's dataframe).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit verbose, but you an try mapping Log to Spark SQL Row:

```
logdstream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.map(log => Row(
    log.timestamp.toDate,
    log.field2,
    ...
  )).toDF().saveAsParquest(...)
})
```

Comment: Hi, Not sure if I understand you correctly. But the error occurs at the statement: val df = elem.toDF(); in other words, I am unable to convert RDD[Log] to dataframe using .toDF() function. Your suggested solution seems to assume that the df is already available?

Comment: You are right, I've missed that. I have changed the answer.